# Check for duplicate dates in table with date intervals in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
ProductId | ValidFrom | ValidTo | Price
```

However it seems that I have some overlapping ValidFrom and ValidTo Dates for the same ProductId's.

How can I create A query that outputs:

```
ProductId | Overlapping Dates
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId,  a.ValidFrom , b.ValidTo FROM 
yourTable a
JOIN yourTable b ON a. ValidFrom BETWEEN b.ValidFrom AND b.ValidTo 
OR a. ValidTo BETWEEN b.ValidFrom AND b.ValidTo
```

Comment: This looks a lot with what I have, However in this case you will also join the same records with eachother. Implying that every record will have an overlapping date

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got there using your response.
However I created a Key for every line based on the productId and the dates.
I only show the rows which are not the same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId,  a.ValidFrom , b.ValidTo FROM 
yourTable a
JOIN yourTable b ON a. ValidFrom BETWEEN b.ValidFrom AND b.ValidTo 
OR a. ValidTo BETWEEN b.ValidFrom AND b.ValidTo 
AND 
(cast(T1.ProductId as nvarchar(50) + Cast(T1.ValidFrom as nvarchar(50)) + Cast(T1.ValidTo        as nvarchar(50)))
<>
(cast(T2.ProductId as nvarchar(50) + Cast(T2.ValidFrom as nvarchar(50)) + Cast(T2.ValidTo     as nvarchar(50)))
```